# How to test axios wrapper

Tags: javascript, api, unit-testing, jestjs, axios

I have no idea how to test `axios` wrapper functions. What should I mock?

I have `createApiClient.js` file:

```
import createApiClient from '../createApiClient';

import axios from 'axios';

function createApiClient(config = {}) {
  const client = axios.create(config);
  client.interceptors.response.use((response) => response.data,
    (error) => {
      if (error.response) {
        throw error.response.data;
      } else {
        throw new Error('Ошибка во время соединения с сервером! Попробуйте повторить попытку позже.');
      }
    });
  return client;
}
export default createApiClient;
```

Also I have concrete `client.js` file created with this function:

```
import createApiClient from '../createApiClient';

const request = createApiClient({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH_API_URL,
});
async function logIn(username, password) {
  const { token } = await request.post('login/', {
    username,
    password,
  });
  return token;
}
// other functions...
export { logIn, register, getUserInfo };
```

How to test `logIn()` and other functions in `client.js`? Especially, I'm wondering about `axios.create()`, `interceptors`, etc.

I tried this and some variations:

```
import createApiClient from '@/api/createApiClient';
import { logIn } from '@/api/auth/client';

const token = 'token';
describe('Тестирование API аутентификации', () => {
  test('log in success', async () => {
    const request = createApiClient();
    request.post = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(token));
    const response = await logIn('foo', 'qwerty');
    response.toBe({ token });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `./createApiClient` module, `createApiClient` function and its returned value.

E.g.

`client.js`:

```js
import createApiClient from './createApiClient';

const request = createApiClient({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH_API_URL,
});

async function logIn(username, password) {
  const { token } = await request.post('login/', {
    username,
    password,
  });
  return token;
}

export { logIn };
```

`createApiClient.js`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

function createApiClient(config = {}) {
  const client = axios.create(config);
  client.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response.data,
    (error) => {
      if (error.response) {
        throw error.response.data;
      } else {
        throw new Error('Ошибка во время соединения с сервером! Попробуйте повторить попытку позже.');
      }
    },
  );
  return client;
}

export default createApiClient;
```

`client.test.js`:

```js
import { logIn } from './client';
import createApiClientMock from './createApiClient';

jest.mock('./createApiClient', () => {
  const axiosInstance = { post: jest.fn() };
  return jest.fn(() => axiosInstance);
});

describe('61713112', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const axiosInstanceMock = createApiClientMock();
    const mResponse = { token: 'token' };
    axiosInstanceMock.post.mockResolvedValueOnce(mResponse);
    const actual = await logIn('foo', 'qwerty');
    expect(actual).toEqual('token');
    expect(axiosInstanceMock.post).toBeCalledWith('login/', { username: 'foo', password: 'qwerty' });
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61713112/client.test.js
  61713112
    ✓ should pass (4ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 client.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.582s, estimated 20s
```

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot. I've been puzzling my head over it for a day.